# Why is my site blank?

Tags: php, html, cpanel, whm, domain-name

Previously, I had my site working perfectly fine. But just recently, I changed my domain name in WHM. When I did, my site was blank. To be technical, here is the HTML code of the "blank site":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body style="padding:0; margin:0;">
        <iframe src="http://mcc.godaddy.com/park/pzgwLzMloTWbMKA2rKczYaOvrt==" style="visibility: visible;height: 2000px;" allowtransparency="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I go to this link `server_ip_address/~username` it comes up with my site fine and it works. Though, when I use my new domain name, it goes to the blank site.

The way in which I changed my domain name was going through WHM. I first went to **Account Functions >> Modify an Account**, and then clicked on the only account I had and clicked edit. On the edit page, I only changed the domain name to the new domain name. Everything else stayed the same. After that, I clicked Save, and everything seemed to be in working order from the WHM side. (BTW the username mentioned above is the same username account I edited)

How can I make my site visible for the new domain name?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console? Do you have a hosts file entry?

Comment: @codehitman nope. no errors.

Comment: Do you have permission to view that url remotely? Check file permissions.

Comment: File permissions? For my index.php file? I'm pretty sure I have permissions because I never touched the files AND I'm able to access the website through `ip_address/~username` (which is mentioned in the question description).

Comment: Is it a new domain? Has the new DNS entry resolved yet?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an ad-blocker.

I get an error in my console

```
http://mcc.godaddy.com/park/pzgwLzMloTWbMKA2rKczYaOvrt==/fe/pzgwLzMloTWbMKA2rKczYaOvrt==?hg=0&nr=0 
Error:  net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

when running with an ad-blocker (and the screen is blank)

I see the site when I disable the adblocker

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: Wow. That showed me the godaddy site. Thanks! Now I know that my domain is parked.

Comment: How do I unpark my domain and make my domain point to `ip_address/~username`? I'm using a dedicated server, not godaddy's shared server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just having a parked domain name, try adding a simple index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Site under construction</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Site under construction.
  </body>
</html>
```

and then recheck if you can see the site.

Comment: What's causing the adblock to block your page is the iframe which contains ads. If you replace the iframe with some text. It will work. You disable adblock it will also work. I notice that following the link in the iframe takes me to the exposeyourfilms.com site domain which is parked. Unpark it and have it serve a simple html file like the one I provided. Any of those three would work.